emails are not sending using nodemailer
I am using smtp.emailcloud.smartping.io as my SMTP service provider.
The emails are sent on my localhost successfully.
But not sending on my server getting below error :
SendMail error: ==>> Error: read ECONNRESET
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
   errno: -104,
   code: 'ESOCKET',
   syscall: 'read',
   command: 'CONN'
}

my code is as below :
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
    port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASS
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    dnsTimeout: 180000, //3 minutes timeout
    debug: true,
    logger: true,
})

const sendEmail = async (emailData) => {
    try {
        const { senderEmail, sendTo, subject, emailBody, attachmentName } = emailData;

        const attachmentPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'uploads/attachments', attachmentName);

        const mailOptions = {
            from: senderEmail,
            to: sendTo,
            subject: subject,
            html: emailBody,
            attachments: attachmentName !== 'null'
                ? [
                    {
                        filename: attachmentName,
                        path: attachmentPath
                    }
                ]
                : []
        }
        if (emailData.cc) {
            mailOptions['cc'] = emailData.cc;
        }
        console.log('mailOptions', mailOptions);
        // transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
            .then(info => console.log('Email sent: ==>>', info))
            .catch(error => console.error('SendMail error: ==>>', error));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error -->>', error);
        Sentry.captureMessage("Something went wrong in sendEmail util function");
        Sentry.captureException(error);
    }
};


I have tried below changes in config :
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASS
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    dnsTimeout: 180000, //3 minutes timeout
    debug: true,
    logger: true,
})


I have tried several solutions from google but did not work.
It would be greate if you help me to resolve it.
Thank you

After trying many solutions from Google and StackOverflow.
I came to know that my code is correct the issue was with SMTP credentials.
I have used other SMTP credentials and it worked.

Can you check the sever network configuration and firewall configuration please?
Before I had a similar problem with NodeJS server but after fixing firewall configuration using ufw or firewalld, it was fine.

I have checked firewall using sudo ufw status command and the Status: inactive.
Still it is not working.
I am using ubuntu server.
